# ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Var_Blend_Coordinates

Tags: package-management, python, compiling

I'm on Ubuntu 18.10

Whilst trying to get this project from GitHub to work: https://github.com/naokishibuya/car-behavioral-cloning

After running "python drive.py model.h5" I'm getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "drive.py", line 30, in <module>
    import utils
  File "/home/michael/Documents/SelfDrive/utils.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2, os
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Var_Blend_Coordinates
```

Fixes I've seen after trying to Google the issue usually concer other Linux distros, like Arch or CentOS, but I haven't seen anyone trying to fix or even report it on Ubuntu yet. In most cases people were connecting this issue with FreeType library and suggested reinstalling or changing version. I don't really know how libraries work on Linux, after checking "sudo apt remove libfreetype6" console reports that almost 1.5GB would be removed so I'm guessing that lot of other libraries depend on this one? I don't dare to proceed, especially If I don't even know that this library is the cause of this issue.

I've tried to run this code on 2 different computers one with Ubuntu 18.04 and one with Debian 9. It didn't work on Ubuntu 18.04 one, so the issue seems be easy to *replicate* on recent Ubuntu releases. And it worked on the second one... But I cannot afford to switch to Debian, because I don't think I could get Unreal Engine to work on that system. (I like Ubuntu more too)

I would be very grateful for any tips on how to get this to work.

Comment: I was getting this with harfbuzz, then after `conda install harfbuzz`, I'm getting effectively the same error with cairo: `import cv2
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Var_Design_Coordinates`

Answer (score 0):

By trial and error I finally managed to get it working. I just had to switch versions of few libraries in my Anaconda enviroment. Those libraries and their versions are:

- Harfbuzz 0.9.39 (I think it could work for any version pre 1.4.1)
- Glib 2.58.2
- Pango 1.39.0

Here is [enviroment file](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/36jJdK4DM7/) content for someone with this error.